# Angular google maps load marker data from JSON

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

I just playing with angular google maps 
https://angular-maps.com/) and paying with an example. on the example marker just write manually.

here the code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MouseEvent } from '@agm/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
})
export class AppComponent  {
  // google maps zoom level
  zoom: number = 10;

  // initial center position for the map
  lat: number = 40.6851128;
  lng: number = -73.8587647;

  clickedMarker(label: string, index: number) {
    console.log(`clicked the marker: ${label || index}`)
  }

  mapClicked($event: MouseEvent) {
    this.markers.push({
      lat: $event.coords.lat,
      lng: $event.coords.lng,
      draggable: true
    });
  }

  markerDragEnd(m: marker, $event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log('dragEnd', m, $event);
  }

  markers: marker[] = [
      {
          lat: 40.760588,
          lng: -73.919405,
          label: 'A',
          draggable: false
      },
      {
          lat: 40.715659,
          lng: -73.907247,
          label: 'A',
          draggable: false
      },
  ]
}
```

here the marker just hard coding, so how to make it dynamic and use external API?...

example :

example.com/api/v1/info/1

```
{
    "name": "Some Location",
    "lat": "40.760588",
    "lng": "-73.919405",
    "status": "ok"
}
```

example.com/api/v1/info/2

```
{
    "name": "Some Location",
    "status": "ok"
}
```

thank you!

Comment: You can create a service layer and use HttpClient to retrieve the data from external API. https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: have you tried this? if my answer worked can you make it the correct answer please

Comment: Hi, Did you down voted my answer? If yes, why? it's fully working code. any feedback is appreciated

Comment: @PatricioVargas, that was not mine, maybe someone doesn't like your answer. I never downvote every answer, respect for people gives time to share knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

In your html File use like this way

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" (mapClick)="click($event)" click='markerClick($event)'>
<agm-marker  *ngFor="let place of markers" [latitude]=place.lat [longitude]=place.lng  title={{place.title}}  (markerClick)="clickedMarker(place.lat, place.lng)" >
<agm-info-window><strong>{{place.label}}</strong></agm-info-window>
</agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

In your app.component.ts typescript file use in this way

```
markers: any[] = [{'lat': 7.289574289959695, 'lng': 80.63236355781555, 'title':  'Town1','label': 'label1'},{ 'lat': 7.468432329097338, 'lng': 80.04151582717896, 'title': 'Town2', 'label': 'label2' }];
```

You can use your own service to fill markers objects from your own source

Comment: You are not showing how to he is he supposed to retrive the data using his service that contains the httpClient

Answer (score 0):

You will have to have an api that is already working or create one. I have created one just to demo it to you. You will have to then use `httpClient`, you create an observable e.g = markers$, then you are going to subscribe to it using the async pipe.

**component.ts**

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
.
.
lat: number = 52.358;
lng: number = 4.916;
markers$ : Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
 this.markers$ = this.getLocations();
}

getLocations(): Observable<any> {
   return this.heroService.getLocations();
}
```

**service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
.
.
BASE_URL = "https://unidosmexico85.firebaseio.com";
LOCATIONS_URL = "/locations.json";
getLocation(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http
  .get(this.BASE_URL + this.LOCATIONS_URL);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" style="height: 500px">
   <div  *ngFor="let marker of markers | async;">
        <agm-marker [latitude]="marker.lat" [longitude]="marker.lng"></agm-marker>
  </div>
</agm-map>
```

The **api** will return a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "locations" : [ {
    "name": "Marker1",
    "lat" : 52.358,
    "lng" : 4.916,
    "status": "okay"
  }, {
    "name": "Marker2",
    "lat" : 40.760588,
    "lng" : -73.919405,
    "status": "not okay"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following html code is to use google map with angular, we use object `markersLocations` which is an JSON object it's value from API.
`latitude` and `longitude` attributes in `<agm-map>` for map center

**HTML**

```
<agm-map  [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [zoom]="zoom">
    <agm-marker *ngIf="markersLocations.length >0" *ngFor="let location of 
    markersLocations" [latitude]="location.latitide" 
    [longitude]="location.langtitude" 
  [iconUrl]="'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/' + location.iconUrl +'.png'">
  </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

**service.ts**

To call a service, you will use `httpclient` in angular so you will add this line of code

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Then use it

```
getLocations() {
    return this.http.get(URL).map((response:Response) => response.json());
 };
```

**in yourcomponent.ts**

1. you will import your service.
2. create instance from service in the
   constructor.
3. calling your API to get JSON file.

**JSON object will be like that**

```
[
    {
        "latitide": 27.9158,
        "langtitude": 34.3300,
        "title": "sharm el sheikh",
        "iconUrl": "yellow-dot"
    },
    {
        "latitide": 30,
        "langtitude": 31,
        "title": "Cairo",
        "iconUrl": "green-dot"
    }
]
```

Comment: You don't need to convert the response to json using .json() in httpClient. That's handled for you by default. In http request you do have tho

Comment: Also, you need to create a subscription to the observable the .get request is creating. Without the subscription you will get a null value